# Aws cognito user migration where MFA is required

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, amazon-cognito-triggers

I want to migrate the cognito users to new user pool where MFA is required and old pool also has the MFA required. I have created the lambda trigger which is getting trigger and returning the required response as follows:

```json
"response": {
      "userAttributes": {
        "email": "test@example.com",
        "email_verified": "true",
        "phone_number": "+917023433333",
        "phone_number_verified": "true"
      },
      "forceAliasCreation": null,
      "finalUserStatus": "CONFIRMED",
      "messageAction": "SUPPRESS",
      "desiredDeliveryMediums": null
}
```

Here is the my event object:

```json
{
    "version": "1",
    "triggerSource": "UserMigration_Authentication",
    "region": "us-east-1",
    "userPoolId": "us-east-1_newPoold",
    "userName": "test@example.com",
    "callerContext": {
        "awsSdkVersion": "aws-sdk-unknown-unknown",
        "clientId": "dddaio06kd1ls20sss5cpgddd"
    },
    "request": {
        "password": "Test@123",
        "validationData": {},
        "userAttributes": null
    },
    "response": {
        "userAttributes": null,
        "forceAliasCreation": null,
        "finalUserStatus": null,
        "messageAction": null,
        "desiredDeliveryMediums": null
    }
}
```

When I tried to migrate the user to new pool where 2fa is not required my script worked and user got created in new pool but same flow is not working for pool with 2FA. I am using this same lambda https://github.com/Collaborne/migrate-cognito-user-pool-lambda/blob/master/src/index.ts

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I noticed in the docs you can pass an `enableSMSMFA` flag in the response, but it doesn't seem to work for me.

Answer (score 1):

After asking AWS customer support I got this working by disabling MFA on the old pool and enabling it on the new one only, plus setting the `enableSMSMFA` property to `true` in the response.